Splunk query visualization day wise with megabyte conversion
I tried writing a Splunk query to show the size of DEBUG and WARN log events for all apps, grouped by day, and display a visualization for comparison. The size should be shown in megabytes. Below is the query I came up with:
index="my-index" env="prod" log.level IN ("DEBUG", "WARN")
| search app="org-*"
| eval log_size=len(_raw)
| timechart span=1d sum(log_size) as daily_log_size by app
| eval daily_log_size_mb=round(daily_log_size/1024/1024, 2)

The problem with this query is that the data in the daily_log_size_mb column is still displayed in bytes instead of megabytes, making it difficult for humans to interpret.
Could you please help me in writing the correct query to achieve the desired output?

I am not sure whether below query which looks like giving me correct answer is actually correct or not.
index="my-index" env="prod" log.level IN ("DEBUG", "WARN")
| search app="org-*"
| eval log_size=len(_raw)
| eval daily_log_size_mb=round(log_size/1024/1024, 2)
| timechart span=1d sum(daily_log_size_mb) as daily_log_size by app
